# A (WEB) Proxy Server with a complete web interface

Tags: reverse-proxy, proxy

I need a web proxy server that has a web interface to configure. I want to be able to take control over proxy server configuration with it's web interface.

Answer (score 2):

How about a linux server and squid? Seems easy enough. You really ought to learn to manage the server via the command line, but if you must have a GUI, [webmin](http://www.webmin.com) has a Squid module.

Answer (score 0):

Squid is my personal fave', u dont need to be a linux admin to get this running. The config and management is easy too (conf files).

SafeSquid is a 3rd party customization on top of Squid and can be managed from a browser. You have to pay though - http://www.safesquid.com/html/portal.php?page=144

Alternately you could google for one of those free windows based proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Squid is best opensource content filter software.

If you want install your own squid on Linux use Webmin.

there are lots of UTM solution who use squid as content filter.

like Untangle, Clearos, Pfsence, Smoothwall, Endian etc.

some commercial distribution like Shopos, Simplewall also provides nice web interface for managing content filter policy.